# Is any there good approach available for parsing HTML resume

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

We need to some information from HTML resume (for example. Experience, Location and etc.,), so we convert HTML content to text content using Strip method than do parsing. My question is this is the good method or i can do any there possible method other this.

**More Info**

> My HTML contents are not having unique HTML tags it may differ.

Hariharan

Comment: currently using html2text script for convert HTML to text.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use HTML parsers in Java. There are some easily available libraries such as:

1. http://jsoup.org/
2. http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's not possible for me to crab string from tags, because my tags dynamic, it may differ each and every time. so is any other possible methods available.

Comment: @harisharju the tags should be possible to iterate over even if you don't know in advance what they are.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak you correct but actually what will do is getting HTML content from multiple job search web sides than parse it. So it's not possible for me to hard code that all tags, what can i do.

Comment: @harisharju [`jsoup:Node#childNodes()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes())

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I think it may help for me. I will do my practice on this and let you know. Thanks